# What is the most efficient way for a control to determine if it's rendering in a Web form or a master page?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I have a control that can be placed in a Web form (.aspx) or a Master Page (.master).  I want it to function differently depending on which one it's in.

My first thought is to climb the control tree back to the root and see if I cross over a MasterPage control.  If so, then it would have to be in the Master Page.

But, this seems inefficient.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if the page has a master page at all. Then go through the control tree to look for a content place holder:

```
public static bool IsInMaster(Control control) {
    if (control.Page.Master == null) return false;
    while (control != null) {
        if (control is ContentPlaceHolder) return false;
        control = control.Parent;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a more efficient way, but if you are climbing up the hierarchy, do so through [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx). You will skip plenty of unnecessary hops by using that.

Unless is a control that will appear lots of time on the page, going through the NamingContainer will be more than enough :)